# Annotation RegexExpression dont work

Tags: c#, regex-negation

Here I try to validate Username and Password with Annotation before checking them into database, but regex doesn't match absolutely correct username and password. For validation  I use this method:

```
public bool IsValid(object obj)
{
    var validationContext = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(obj);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, validationContext, validationResults, true);

    return isValid;
}
```

But `Username = Vladimir12` and `Password = vovata12` don't match. Here is the AccountLoginDto.cs:

```
public class AccountLoginDTO
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z]{6-12}$")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-z]{6-12}$")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I call method:

```
var dto = new AccountLoginDTO
{
    Username = username,
    Password = passwword
};

if (!validation.IsValid(dto))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(IncorectInput);
}
```

Take Exception because username and password not matched.

Answer (score 1):

`{6-12}` is not valid, use `{6,12}` instead if you want to allow length between 6 and 12 characters for that set.